# Multiple checkbox checked value

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have written the following code in JSFiddle to able so get the sum of combined values of the checkboxes.

Script

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
        total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');

 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
        }
    }
```

Code

```
<input value="33" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
    <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
        <input value="62" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
<span id="payment-total">0</span>
```

There it works perfect, when I implement this in my system there is no reslut or any error.
The checkboxes in my system are genarated by an MySQL output.

Any suggestions what migh be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious, how is that sum useful?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably running before the elements are dynamically generated, so the event handlers are not being attached. Try delegating the event handlers using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method:

```js
$total = $('#payment-total');
$(document).on("click", ".sum", function() {
  var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
  $total.text(function(i, value) {
      return parseFloat(value) + add;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="33" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
<input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
<input value="62" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">
<span id="payment-total">0</span>
```

Comment: When I move the checkboxes to the first part of the page where nothing is dynamically generated the problem is still there.

Comment: @Muiter The problem is not there in the demo..? Maybe create an online demo demonstrating the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use pure javascript for your solution because you didn't use Jquery on your code. I think problem reason comes from **Javascript eventListener**. When you create a new element to your document, you should add its events.

In first code i create a checkbox but this is not work as others. [link_1](http://jsfiddle.net/3oweu107/1/)

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/3oweu107/1/>
```

However in second code i add event as other checkbox so payment-total value calculation done by new event. [link_2](http://jsfiddle.net/3oweu107/2/)

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/3oweu107/2/>
```

i hope this will help your problem :)

Comment: When I move the checkboxes from the loop genarated by MySQl it is still not working, so the problem is not in that part.